# Node.js, Express.js - unexpected token {

Tags: node.js, express, unexpected-token

My app crashes every time it reaches this line:

```
const {name, price} = req.query;
        ^
```

can't seem to locate the exact answer..here is the error log

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
```

context:

```
app.get('/products/add' , (req, res) => {
  const {name, price} = req.query;

  const INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY = `INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('${ name }', ${ price })`;
  connection.query(INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err,results) => {
      if(err)
      {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      else
      {
        return res.send('succesfully added product');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: node version: 4.8.6

Answer (score 5):

According to [node.green](http://node.green/), the [object destructuring with primitives](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations-object-destructuring-with-primitives) syntax works after Node.JS v6.4.0, and throws the `Unexpected Token {` on Node.js versions below that.

Also, the [object rest/spread properties](http://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties) only works out of the box from Node v8.6.0. It works in v8.2.1 with the `--harmony` flag, and throws the `Unexpected Token ...` on Node.js versions below that.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to use `destructuring assignment`. AFAIK its support by nodejs v.6+ from a box and from 4.2.2 with flag `--harmony_destructuring`